# Count of used parameters

Tags: python

I have a function that takes multiple lists as input. I'm counting the number of them that are active parameters (not None). I'm currently doing it like this:

```
def x(l1, l2, l3):
    …
    count = 0
    if l1:
        count += 1
    if l2:
        count += 1
    if l3:
        count += 1
    …
```

Isn't there a better (and prettier) way for doing this?

Comment: Does any empty list count? (That is, do you want to distinguish between `None` and `[]`)?

Comment: I don't need to add empty lists to the count thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your function to take an arbitrary number of args, it gets a lot neater:

```
def x(*args):
    count = sum(bool(arg) for arg in args)
    ...
```

Otherwise you could reconstruct the equivalent of `args` based on the named parameters:

```
def x(l1, l2, l3):
    …
    count = sum(bool(arg) for arg in (l1, l2, l3))
    …
```

Note that `bool(arg)` has the same behavior as your `if l1: ...` checks -- it converts a "truthy" arg to `True` (which counts as `1` when you `sum` it).  If you wanted to check specifically for `None` (as opposed to an empty list or any other "falsey" arg) you'd do `arg is not None`.

Comment: This wouldn't count empty lists, which might not be the intent of the question (as they specifically mention `None`).

Comment: I considered that, but their original code doesn't count empty lists either, so I opted to preserve their apparent intent.  Obviously an easy fix either way if they discover they don't want that behavior.  The point of their question seems to be about doing the count via iteration rather than copy+paste, not how to detect whether a parameter is "active".

Comment: Yeah, I've asked in a comment just to clarify.

Comment: Is there a reason why l1, l2 and l3 are in a set? Does it change something from putting them in a list like [l1, l2, l3]?

Comment: @tomcajot It's not a set, it's a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). It doesn't make much difference, possibly less memory...

Comment: It doesn't really matter (to the `for` loop, anyway) what type is used, as long as it is an *iterable* type. `for x in foo` implicitly calls `iter(foo)` in order to get something to iterate over.

Comment: Even if you write `... for arg in [l1, l2, l3]`, it appears that (C)Python builds a tuple anyway, based on the byte code generated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you have such a repeating pattern with one very slight difference - a loop is in place:

```py
def x(l1, l2, l3):
    …
    count = 0
    for l in [l1, l2, l3]:
        if l:
            count += 1
    …
```

This makes the code more verbose because if more lists (arguments) are added, you only need to add them once to the list in the loop, instead of adding a new `if` statement for each one...

This was intended to be as similar as your original code as possible. For a shorter, more *"pythonic"* code, see [@Samwise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799759/samwise)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223974/6045800).